# Qualtrics: Adding Different Characters before/after Text Boxes in Matrix Table

Tags: javascript, textbox, qualtrics

Trying to find a way to have different characters appears before/after text boxes in a matrix question. Currently, I have one column in the table asking for a dollar amount and the second column asking for a percentage. I really wan to avoid splitting them into separate questions since they are related.

I found the following code on Qualtrics' website but it adds a dollar sign to every text box, which I do not want.

```
var inputs = $(this.getQuestionContainer()).select('input[type="text"]');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];

  $(input).insert({before: '$'});
}
```

Any idea if this is even feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dollars is the the first answer column (c4) and percents is the second answer column (c5) (the row labels and vertical divider are c1-c3), modify your code to:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    function hasClass(element, cls) {
        return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
    }

    var inputs = $(this.getQuestionContainer()).select('input[type="text"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(hasClass(input.up(), 'c4')) {
            $(input).insert({before: '$'});
            input.style.display = "inline";
        }   
        else if(hasClass(input.up(), 'c5')) {
            $(input).insert({after: '%'});
            input.style.display = "inline";
        }   
    }   
});
```

input.up() gets you to the `<td>` where you can check for class c4 or c5. Setting display to "inline" prevents the $ from appearing above or the 
% from appearing below the text input.

Answer (score 1):

The code above works well for a Matrix Table, text entry format. You can also modify that code slightly to add characters before or after Qualtrics's general "Text Entry" question format. Qualtrics doesn't add incremental column classes in the same way for general Text Entry questions, it only uses "ControlContainer" as the class. The following code inserts a '%' symbol after the text field(s). You can replace the '%' with whatever characters you need for your label.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    function hasClass(element, cls) {
        return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
    }

    var inputs = $(this.getQuestionContainer()).select('input[type="text"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(hasClass(input.up(), 'ControlContainer')) {
            $(input).insert({after: '%'});
            input.style.display = "inline";
        }   
    }   
});
```